# How can I add multiple App connections in my zapier account using Zapier's Webhook or API

Tags: zapier, xero-api, zapier-cli

[image]

I can add a xero connection manually but want to add multiple through an API or webhook. I cannot find anything regarding this on the Zapier documentatioj

I could not find any API or webhook to programatically add connections or manipulate them